# MySQL is getting slower

Tags: php, mysql, performance, database-performance

In `php` application `MySQL` is getting slower sometimes. When I do restart mysql service, then it works fine.

Here are some key configurations I did in `my.cnf` file:

```
skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve
```

I also enabled and checked `slow query logs`. There is nothing in there as it's *intermittent* problem.

All users are associated with server IP address.

**MySQL Tunner Suggestion:**

-------- Performance Metrics ------------------------------------------

[--] Up for: 19h 23m 22s (5K q [0.072 qps], 1K conn, TX: 2M, RX: 606K)

[--] Reads / Writes: 99% / 1%

[--] Binary logging is disabled

[--] Total buffers: 1.1G global + 2.7M per thread (5000 max threads)

[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 1.1G (32.15% of installed RAM)

[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 14.2G (422.17% of installed RAM)

[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/5K)

[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 0% (4/5000)

[!!] Aborted connections: 4.72%  (89/1886)

[!!] Query cache is disabled

[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 92 sorts)

[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 70% (608 on disk / 868 total)

[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (4 created / 1K connections)

[OK] Table cache hit rate: 95% (166 open / 173 opened)

[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (76/25K)

[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (2K immediate / 2K locks)

Let me know if you need more information in order to solve this problem.

Comment: How did you measure the performance downgrade? What does `top` say when its "slow"? Maybe your slow query threshold is too high to whats really happening

Comment: which database engine do you use?

Comment: @EhsanKhodarahmi: innoDB

Answer (score 0):

Check [Mysql Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html) first

And maybe you are in 75% system waits, most probably due to heavy swapping.

1. use mysqltuner.pl to find what are your variables that affect memory
   usage
2. press "m" when in top to see what ate the memory
3. use free -m to see how much is cached
4. use iotop to see who is eating the IO

EXPLAIN Extended command shows details about your queries when your have no idea what is happening http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-extended.html

Make use of Query Cache http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-configuration.html

Make sure that your MySQL server configuration file options are optimized according to your hardware http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html

Make sure that you are using optimized data types while creating a table structure For example "Comments" fields has size of 256 characters, reply it to MYSQL with a field with type VARCHAR(256) instead of using TEXT. The query will be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
[--] Total buffers: 1.1G global + 2.7M per thread (5000 max threads)
```

Is related to this:

```
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 14.2G (422.17% of installed RAM)
```

Which is bad because once you start using more RAM than you have available in your system you start swapping to disk and performance will tank, *sharply*.

There is no good reason for this, ever:

```
[!!] Query cache is disabled
```

Getting your memory usage in check may help address this:

```
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 70% (608 on disk / 868 total)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out those things. Can you elaborate on how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When using INNODB, overall DBMS performance depends to a lot of configurations (in my.ini) and tuning them is an experimental job that depends to vast range of factors from physical capabilities to table indexing to join or even sort queries.
In general, I guess the most important INNODB configuration property is `innodb_buffer_pool_size`

> InnoDB, unlike MyISAM, uses a buffer pool to cache both indexes and row data. The bigger you set this the less disk I/O is needed to access data in tables. On a dedicated database server you may set this parameter up to 80% of the machine physical memory size. Do not set it too large, though, because competition of the physical memory may cause paging in the operating system.

If your database has growed up recently and `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is small, it would be first suspicion point. Of course changing this property (usually with some other parameters such as `innodb_log_file_size`) is a pain, because you have to dump and restore all of your data.
If it didn't work, then you should consider about other possiblities, which is not a straightforward matter.

Comment: I have `14G` memory on my server. And I don't have dedicated database server. `PHP` is also running under the same server. And `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is `1G` in my current configuration. Is that ok?

Comment: I can't say it's OK or not because it depends on size of your database (indexed data). If size of your database is not considerable (compare to `innodb_buffer_pool_size`), then you should think about other possibilities such as `tmp_table_size` or `query_cache_size`

Answer (score 0):

max_connections = 100 -- not 5000
long_query_time = 1  -- to make the slow log more usable
Keep the slowlog on
leave the query cache off
(608 on disk / 868 total) --> DO look at the slow log
Use pt-query-digest to find the 'worst' query.